# Custom UIViewController on instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

To put it simply:

Interface Builder allows you to assign a certain UIViewController-based class in a storyboard to a custom view controller and to identify it by specifying any ID as storyboardID.

Calling UIStoryBoard's instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier will instantiate it and return the id of the instantiated view controller, so far, so good. No here's the challenge:

My Storyboard layout is quite complicated and I want to use it from different UIViewController-based classes. A simple method would be simply duplicating the scene, and to assign a different class and ID. This, however, will blow up the storyboard and, if the same layout is used by several controllers, put up additional overhead.

So I thought about a method, to instantiate a view controller with a programatically defined class (depending on the App's state) and I did not find any feasible way. I thought of something simple like:

```
UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:viewIdentifier usingClass:aClass];
```

Any idea out there?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I was too focussed on UIStoryboard/NIB issues. After finding it, the answer is pretty simple. Just ovewrride awakeFromNib in the base class and set a new class (which, naturally, must be based on the base class and not define any additional content).

```
- (void) awakeFromNib
{
    Class aNewClass = /* whatever's needed to find the correct class ... */
    object_setClass(self, aNewClass);
}
```

That's it. instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier will already return the new class.

Comment: Ah, don't forget: #import <objc/runtime.h>